# How does the coherence of a spin state relate to the physical concept of "coherence"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, coherence

In my textbook the coherence of a spin state $|\psi\rangle $ is measured by the quantity $|\langle \uparrow|\psi| \downarrow \rangle|$. The thing is that I am not sure how this quantity is related to the physical concept of coherence. So is there anybody who could motivate why this quantity actually measures coherence?

Comment: There's something wrong here: if $\left|\Psi\right\rangle$ is a state then the expression $|\left\langle \uparrow \right| \Psi \left| \downarrow \right\rangle|$ doesn't make any sense. Perhaps $\Psi$ is actually a density matrix here.

Comment: This is just the size of the off-diagonal term in the density matrix $\Psi$.

Comment: @PeterShor: Indeed, but OP wrote $|\psi\rangle$ which leads me to believe that he/she is thinking of $\psi$ as a vector rather than a density matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose I have two different spins, spin $A$ is in state $\left|\uparrow \right\rangle$ and sping $B$ is in state $\left|\downarrow \right\rangle$.
I give you one of these spins randomly, so you have a 1/2 probability of spin up and 1/2 probability of spin down.
There's no coherence between up and down because you either have a spin which is definitely up *or* you have one which is definitely down.
The density matrix for this situation is

$$\rho =
\frac{1}{2} |A\rangle \langle A| + \frac{1}{2} |B\rangle \langle B| =
\frac{1}{2} \left(
\left|\uparrow\right\rangle\left\langle\uparrow\right| +
\left|\downarrow\right\rangle\left\langle\downarrow\right|
\right) =
\frac{1}{2} \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) \, .
$$

Now if we compute $\left\langle \uparrow \right| \rho \left| \downarrow \right\rangle$ we get zero.
This is because there are no off-diagonal terms in $\rho$.
Physically this means that if we were to measure $\langle\sigma_x\rangle$ we would get zero:$^{[a]}$

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\langle A | \sigma_x | A \rangle = 0, \quad \text{probability }=1/2 \\
\langle B | \sigma_x | B \rangle = 0, \quad \text{probability }=1/2 \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Now suppose instead I gave you

$$
|C\rangle =
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \left|\uparrow\right\rangle+\left|\downarrow\right\rangle \right) \, .$$

This is a true quantum superposition of spin up and down.
You can't think of this as classical probability of spin up *or* spin down.
The density matrix is

$$\rho = 
|C\rangle \langle C| =
\frac{1}{2} \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right) =
\frac{1}{2} \left(
\left|\uparrow\right\rangle\left\langle\uparrow\right| +
\left|\downarrow\right\rangle\left\langle\downarrow\right| +
\left|\downarrow\right\rangle\left\langle\uparrow\right| +
\left|\uparrow\right\rangle\left\langle\downarrow\right|
\right)$$

and you can compute that $\left\langle\uparrow \right| \rho \left| \downarrow \right\rangle = 1$.
So you see that the nonzero value of $\left\langle\uparrow \right| \rho \left| \downarrow \right\rangle$ directly detects whether or not the state has coherence.
Physically this corresponds to the fact that in this state $\langle \sigma_x \rangle = 1 \neq 0$.

$[a]$: The same is true for measuring $\sigma_y$.

Comment: What I don't understand is how this coherence is related to the quantum coherence defined by Glauber. He introduced the notion that a state is coherent, if it is an eigenstate to the annihilation operator?

Comment: @XinWang: Those are completely different uses of the word "coherent". A state of the harmonic oscillator which is an eigenstate of the annihilation operator is called a "coherent state". The word "coherent" *also* means a state which has off-diagonal elements in the density matrix. This can apply to spin or any other system. Note that there are *also* so-called "coherent spin states" which are like the "coherent states" of the harmonic oscillator. The word use is very confusing.

Comment: but how is this notion related to the coherence we know from classical mechanics, where there has to be a constant phase difference between two objects or are all these ideas different from each other?

Comment: The off-diagonal elements in the density matrix tell you that various terms in the quantum superposition have a specific *quantum* phase difference. When the relative phases are randomized you get the classical state, i.e. the quantum state decoheres.